# How to add a contacts to contact book in own program?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, abaddressbook

I want to ask a question about the iPhone application. The application can let the user to enter the information in a costumed table (not the contacts book). After that, the program will use the retrieved data to add to the address book. But I don't how to add the content to contacts book. Can any one help me? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The framework you are looking for is the AddressBook framework, and the guide within the SDK is called "Address Book Programming Guide for iPhone OS"

The method that does this is called ABAddressBookAddRecord